# Почему не загружаются страницы на сайте laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, apache

Делал пробный проект laravel, используя php artisan serve - всё работает. Всё хорошо. Решил после этого перекинуть на apache. И тут понеслись проблемы.

1. Почему-то у меня воспринимается только https. То есть проект открывает главную страницу только на hhtps. *Даже если я удалю из smarthouse.conf описание 443 порта (тогда вообще работать не будет)*
2. С главной страницы я никуда не могу перейти. Везде выскакивает ошибка, что такого URL не обнаружено.

**smarthouse.conf из sites-available**

```
 <IfModule mod_ssl.c>

<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin user@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/smarthome/public

ServerName smarthome.loc
<Directory /var/www/smarthouse/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride All

        Require all granted

</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin user@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/smarthome/public
<Directory /var/www/smarthouse/public>

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride All

        Require all granted

</Directory>

    ServerName smarthome
    ServerAlias smarthome.ru smarthome.com smarthouse smarthouse.com smarthouse.ru smarthome.loc

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Команда ****a2enmode** rewrite** прописана.
В apache2.conf прописан сам модуль.

**.htaccess в корневой папке проекта**

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d RewriteRule ^ ./index.php [L]
</IfModule?
```

**.htaccess из папки public**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Файл .env**

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:keeeyyy=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug
```

**Фрагмент из app.php**

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL'),
```

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('main');
})->name('mainPage');

Route::get('/about', function () {
    return view('about');
})->name('aboutPage');

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return view('contact');
})->name('contactPage');
```

**Правка № 1**
*Изменил  для закрытия 443*

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin user@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/smarthome/public
ServerName smarthome.loc
<Directory /var/www/smarthouse/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin user@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/smarthome/public
<Directory /var/www/smarthouse/public>

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

        AllowOverride All

        Require all granted

</Directory>

    ServerName smarthome
    ServerAlias smarthome.ru smarthome.com smarthouse smarthouse.com smarthouse.ru smarthome.loc

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: `<IfModule mod_ssl.c>` закрывайте перед `<VirtualHost *:80>`

Comment: @InDevX, спасибо за совет. Это к сожалению никак не помогло.  Всё так же открывается лишь главная страница и только через https. Если я пробую удалить virtual host на 443, то http не открывается. Пытается перекинуть на https.